# How to backup Windows (Server 2016) Language-Settings

Tags: windows, configuration, registry

within a project I need to use a jump server which is reset on a regular base. That means that I have to re-setup my working environment after each reset. For this I wrote a PowerShell script which exports different parts of the registry and copies configuration files. A second script reinstalls that information back after reset.

Now I need to use a kind of complicated language setup - main language for displaying HTML-pages has to be English, but other things should be using German. So I added via the language settings english as main diplay language but changed the input to a German keyboard.

The only place I found langauge information stored was within the registry key "HKCU\Keyboard Layout". But this does not seem to contain all information since after uploading the saved configuration onto the jump server after a reset there was no language selector on the taskbar next to the clock.

In the language settings dialogue (control panel - add language) english was installed, but as second language.

What other places does Windows (Server 2016) store information for the language settings of a user?

Cheers for your help
Carsten

Comment: I'm not sure if these are available in Windows Server 2016, but have you looked at  `HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Preload` and `HKCU\Keyboard Layout\Substitutes`?

Comment: Those keys exist on Windows Server 2016 and since I export the complete HKCU\Keyboard Layout those are also within the reg-file I load on restore. 
I added also HKCU\Control Panel\International and HKCU\Control Panel\Keyboard to the set I am exporting for this issue, but to no avail. I still have to set up the language settings manually.